How to disable font scaling of dropdown placeholder text and selected text from that dropdown in react native
I'm using the dropdown package react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.12.1" I want to disable the font scaling of not only the placeholder text but also when the dropdown value is selected and the field is covered with that selected text.
The dropdown code is below:
        <View style={styles.dropdownContainer}>
          <Dropdown
            style={styles.dropdown}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
            data={countries}
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            placeholder={
              <CustomText
                style={styles.placeholderStyle}
                children={"Country"}
              />
            }
            // placeholder="Country"
            value={address.country}
            onChange={(item) => {
              handleChange("country", item.value);
            }}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            renderSelectedItem={(item) => (
              <CustomText
                style={styles.selectedTextStyle}
                children={item.label}
              />
            )}
          />
        </View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dropdownContainer: {
    height: 50,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 10,
    // paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 7,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  dropdown: {
    height: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    // borderWidth: 0.5,
  },
  placeholderStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "gray",
    allowFontScaling: false,
  },
  selectedTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "black",
    allowFontScaling: false,
  },
  inputSearchStyle: {
    height: 40,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

I tried making a CustomText component in making the text of placeholder and selected text come under the Text component so i could do allowFontScaling={false} but that didn't work out as well. The component's code:
const CustomText = ({ style, children }) => {
  return (
    <Text style={style} allowFontScaling={false}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!
